# Saving multiple gameObjects in the Index of a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a list in which I can save all the gameObjects that move in a instance of time (with an instance of time I mean each time the player doeas an action. Moving one unit up, down, left, right) and I also want the index of the gameObject is the same as the time.
The problem is that when restarting the level or pushing boxes I need to save more that one gameObject on the list.

I have thought about converting all the gameObjects that have moved in an instance of time into a string, and the separate the string when I need to acces the game objects:

The list would look like this: (it's not code, it just represents what would be saved in each index)

```
List <String> objectsOfMovement:
Index [0] = " "
Index [1] = "player gameObject"
Index [2] =  "playergameObject box1gameObject box2gameObject"
Index [3] = "playergameObject box1gameObject box2gameObjec"
Index [4] = " "
```

" " = means that the player has waited (when presing L ctrl one unit of time passes but the player position does not change)

But this aproach seems more complicated than it should be, because of this I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

Thanks you in advance.